# How to properly interface button switches meters away from the host

Tags: switches, interface

I plan to place some buttons at about 50 meters (roundtrip) away from the host and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

The I/O reading the signal will be from an [MCP23S17](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20001952c.pdf) 16bit GPIO expansion IC that will be connected to a [MAX6818](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX6816-MAX6818.pdf) octal switch debouncer which basically handles the debouncing of the mechanical switches and at the same time offers ESD protection. They will be powered by 3.3 volts. The wire will be stranded 14 gauge wire and I will also twist them to at least make it less susceptible to inteferences.

I have come up with two ways, but if you know a better way please do say.

[image]

The first one is to just straight up connect the wires to output of the doubouncer with a resistor. I'm not sure if the resistor is necessary, but I guess to help with the ESD strikes since a 50meter 14guage wire only has 0.016 ohms of resistance which some may consider already as a short.

The second one is from a article I read, with the use of optocouplers. Although I think this is a safer solution, I am not sure if the added optocoupler and another power supply can justify its benefits because what I think the optocoupler is used for is to prevent ESD strikes but the  MAX6168 already has a ESD protection built into it.

Please share to me you thoughts on which configuration should I take, or if you have a better configuration.

Comment: What's the operating environment? Are we talking about lots of motors, generators, x-ray machines, and buried next to the Large Hadron Collector? Or just something pedestrian? Also, you might consider using CAT6 cable. It includes four wire pairs that are twisted as well as shielded. So very cheap, nice, and you wire up to four switches at a time.

Comment: @just just home use, and i think the worst we have here is a water pump motor but can we assume a bit more harsher environment so that it will last a bit longer. The wires will most likely not go alongside the inductive loads, but i think its better to built it that it could. I did consider ethernet cables since they are already twisted but we already have a left over spool of 14 AWG and im planning to use those instead.

Comment: Is this just ***one*** switch? Or are we talking "lots"? Also, do you have to handle the case where you can detect when three switches are activated and be able to figure which of them are activated and at what times? Or will only one at a time be activated (if more than one?) Finally, you'll need some kind of additional circuitry for the opto, unless you buy certain optos in particular.

Comment: @jonk 8 separate switches to be exact, and any number can be "on" at any given time. The sequence of which the switch are pressed are not necessary. as long as the host can detect that a channel changed state that is all it matters. For the opto i have not chosen an exact part yet, but yes complementary components will be present if needed for the type of opto. What type of opto do you recommend?

Comment: If you like optos, the 6N137 is kind of nice to have. They work pretty nicely. Simple pull-up on the output is enough. 5 V device, though.

Comment: @jonk what about any potential 50 or 60 Hz wave riding on the long wire? See my answer for noise filtering.

Comment: @AbdullahBaig From the datasheet, *"Ground loop elimination, noise isolation"* and *" guaranteed common mode transient immunity of 5 kV/μs and 15 kV/μs."* It's been pretty bullet-proof, my experience. I don't mean to disparage less boutique, cheaper solutions. Just the OP seemed to be considering optos.

Comment: @jonk those are some pricy optos, for the dual channel (3$ for duals and 1$ for single) what a weird pricing. But the dual channel going to bite me space wise so I tried looking for an alternative, with about the same specs you highlighted.  What do you think of this one [ILQ2-700T](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83646/ild1.pdf)

Comment: @jonk i got that from [these list](https://bit.ly/3i9S50o) it has 1$ parts for 4 channels, but i went with the fastest rise/fall time,

Comment: @Jakequin Yeah. Pricey, but very fast and they do most of the work so I don't have to suggest a detailed schematic. Regular optos require a little extra to make them work well.

Comment: 4N25 are available in my city for about $ 0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I plan to place button at about 50 meters (roundtrip) away from the
> host*

The chip in question: -

[image]

The spec for the chip is insufficient to provide protection against indirect lightning current surges and this is likely to be a problem with 25 metres of unshielded (or shielded) wiring (inside a home or outside).

Given that the inputs can exceed the power rails by +/- 25 volts, you might consider using appropriately rated TVS diodes that can withstand IEC 6100-4-5 indirect lightning surges.

$$\boxed{\text{OR}}$$

Use an opto-isolator (but don't forget the pull-up resistor on the collector).

Comment: For the opto-isolator what do you think of the [ILQ2-X009T](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83646/ild1.pdf). It does not the IEC 6100 but it has other ratings it seems. Would they be able to survive several indirect lightning strikes in their lifespan. The max6816 already has pull up but the optocoupler seems to need 1k ohms, so yeah a pull-up

Comment: Is your host's 0 volts truly grounded or floating? Personally I don't see any benefit from using an opto-isolator. Peak surge current is only 2.5 amps and you can get 50 amps from an IEC 61000-4-5 2kV rated surge because it uses a source impedance of 42 ohms.

Comment: I dont quite understand what you mean by 0v or floating, the ground in the schematics is the same as digital ground or the one connected to "GND" or "-" marking of  the supply. If you are talking about the opto-isolator, the led side will be powered by a different power supply with its own ground. the ground on the LED side wont be connected to the ground of the host (as opposed to the given schematic).So you would rather do a circuit like Abdullah Baig answer than use an opto-isolator?

Comment: I meant is the circuit earthed? No, I would use TVS diodes.

Comment: Ahh apologies proteus use that symbol for its default ground. It is not earthed. So just straight up place a better diode at the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Use an RC filter like this to remove any high frequency interference.

R1, R2 and C1 should be as close to the MAX6818 as possible. Do not connect the GND end of the push button to the local ground, leave it floating. Use a shielded, twisted pair for the long cable. A shielded twisted pair is better than an unshielded pair, but it really depends on how much interference is present in the environment.

The MAX6818 has an internal pull up resistor, but it is too high (33-100 k in the datasheet) to build a reasonable RC filter, so we have to use an external pull up resistor. The inputs of MAX6818 are ESD protected, so an optocoupler is not necessary. This circuit may introduce a delay in the range of tens of milliseconds (in addition to the ~50 ms delay by MAX6818), which is not of any significant concern for you, I hope.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMscu8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I dont think i can have shielded twisted pairs, as i plan to use some excess 14 guage wire that i have. Is it critical ? Im still not fixed for the optocoupler, im still thinking if i should go with the extra protection just incase someone will connect something to those line which they shouldnt.

Comment: Aren't RC filters resistor first before capacitor( i really have no idea if they can be interchanged) ?

Comment: If you have loose wire, twist the pair. It is better than being untwisted. Shielding is not absolutely necessary, but it all depends on how much interference you have.

Comment: You are right about RC filters. R2 and C1 make up the filter, and they block the high frequency signals coming from the long wire (acts as an antenna) from entering the MAX6818.

Comment: Optocoupler will be good for extra protection. But it will only be truly useful if you use a separate 5V supply with it. If you use the same supply for the MAX6818 and the optocoupler, then it's like filtering your water before drinking, but drinking it in a dirty glass.